# Best portable method to implement an algorithm on Website

Tags: language-agnostic

I came across this problem,I have got an algorithm that I need to implement on websites.
The server side scripts may differ and it can be PHP,ASP.NET etc.
All I need to do to is to deliver the binary(I need it as I dont want this security algorithm to be open and viewable) that can comply by every type.As per me solution can be (Please correct me if I am wrong):-

1. Implementing binary according to OS.
2. Implementing Algo as per every type of script.(Tough and less portable)
   Please suggest if there is other way round or please close this question and redirect me to any earlier question asked for this situation.I am new for this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to use Java Server-side technologies to implement your algorithm. You can write your algorithm as a java class, which can be called from a Servlet or a JSP or even any other technologies over http protocol. The main reason why I suggest using java is:

1) it is platform independent, so your 1st point:

> 1. Implementing binary according to OS.

You dont have to worry which OS the client would use.and it can be ported to other OS very easily.

and

2) it will be very secure, once you compile, a class file will be generated, which can be delivered. it cant be opened and viewable.

Comment: plz let me know, What if client doesnt agree to implement JSP.and insists on using PHP,or something else...

Comment: In that case you can implement that algorithm as a web-service and call it from your PHP page. In that way you can be assured that your web-service cannot be opened and viewed by anyone? nobody can see your code.they can just call your service

Comment: You can write a web-service in java using JAX-WS or even if you want to cross-platform web-services you can use Apache Thrift.